# Excel 2007 - changes on one sheet affecting other (without cell references)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

Some strange behaviour I've encountered twice in Excel is that changes made to one sheet would be duplicated on another sheet in the same workbook. The first time, I typed values into a few cells on sheet 1, and the corresponding cells in sheet 2 also changed. There were cell references involved. It was as if there was carbon paper between the two sheets.

The second time, on sheet 1 I copied a formula at A4 over the 1000 cells below it. On sheet 2, a formula that happened to be on A4 got copied over the 1000 cells below it, destroying the sheet in the process.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more than one worksheet selected then any edits you make will be on all of them.

To select/deselect multiple worksheets, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> while left clicking on the worksheet tabs.

The image below shows Sheet1 and Sheet2 selected, while Sheet3 is not. Any edits made on Sheet2 will also be applied to Sheet1.

[image: Excel tabs]

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly my problem. Sometimes I would intend to select an entire area and accidentally click CTRL+SHIFT+PAGEDOWN instead of CTRL+SHIFT+ARROWDOWN.